# TeamCity trigger on specific parameter value

Tags: teamcity

I have set an automatic teamcity flow. I have 2 projects A and B.

**Project B** will trigger when **Project A** has a successful build finish.

In **project A** I can select a build configuration (development, test or production). I want **project B** to trigger when **Project A** build finish AND only if selected configuration is development.

How can I manage it to check the configuration type on the trigger? Is it a new one?

TeamCity version I use is 2022.04.1